# How do I maximize scanning area in TWAIN?

Tags: c, windows, twain

My users tend to insert their paper in the scanner feeder somewhat randomly, and the default setting of A4 sometimes doesn't cut it - part of the image is cut away. How can I tell TWAIN to scan as big an image as possible?

I'm using EZTWAIN classic. I cannot find there appropriate function for that, and buying EZTWAIN Pro is out of question, so probably the only way is to talk directly with TWAIN.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call TWAIN_SetPaperSize before calling TWAIN_SetRegion
Refer to Page 133 and 136 in www.dosadi.com/pub/eztp/EZTwain_User_Guide.pdf

Comment: I'm sorry for taking so long to answer, but that function seems to be unavailable in EZTWAIN Classic. Like I said, buying Pro is not an option, unfortunately :(